# Calculating $\int_{\pi}^{\infty} \cfrac{\cos(x+t)}{t} dt$

Tags: improper-integrals

I'm having trouble calculating the integral:
$$\int_{\pi}^{\infty} \cfrac{\cos(x+t)}{t} dt$$
 Can anyone help me with this I have no clue what to do.

Comment: take a look the defintions for cosine and sine integrals. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral

Comment: Does this integral converge in the first place ?

Comment: Are you supposed to evaluate it or just prove con/divergence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This involves special functions.*

$$\cos(x+t)=\cos(x)\cos(t)-\sin(x)\sin(t)$$ makes 
$$\int \cfrac{\cos(x+t)}{t}\, dt=\cos(x)\int \cfrac{\cos(t)}{t} dt-\sin(x)\int \cfrac{\sin(t)}{t} dt=\text{Ci}(t) \cos (x)-\text{Si}(t) \sin (x)$$ where appear the [sine and cosine integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral).